# AWS RDS- Determine what Database Tables aren't interacted with?

Tags: databases, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-rds

Is it possible to have AWS-RDS (or another aws service) generate a report on databases that haven't been interacted with (write/read) after a certain period of time?

My background is in QA and I'm relatively new to the DevOps game, sorry if this is a basic question, couldn't find it in search.

Comment: What about checking AWS CloudWatch? If there is no activity then there is no interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any database services "internal traffic" is available to AWS services directly.

That being said, you should be able to dump all sql queries to a log file on S3 and also extract all database/table combinations to a text file as well.

It then becomes a text processing exercise that you can possibly solve with AWS Athena